# Showing the Hopf fibration has no global sections

Tags: general-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, line-bundles

Let's consider a principle $U(1)$-bundle over $S^2$ with the transition function $g_{\infty 0} = z/|z|$ (it is known as the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration)). There is a simple topological argument showing that this bundle is not trivial by the comparison of fundamental groups. However, it should be clear directly from definitions.

So I would like to prove that this bundle has no global sections (which is equivalent to non-triviality). It means that there is no continuous function $f: \mathbb{C} \to U(1)$ such that there exists $$ \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{z}{|z|} f(z) $$ How would one prove this?

Comment: Can you link to the topological argument that you refer to?

Comment: The bundle space is just $S^3$ so $\pi_1(S_3) = 0$. If it were a direct product then the fundamental group would be $\pi_1(S_2 \times S_1) \neq 0$.

Comment: I think you could use higher homotopy groups too, although that's probably not the argument you want. I think the point for me at least is that topological arguments such as the one you presented make this problem much much easier. I'm not sure if youd even want to prove it a different way.

Comment: The point is that these simple and powerful topological techniques definitely allow to solve the problem but at the same time they hide what happens at the level of definitions. Having the purpose of understanding something about fiber bundles I would like to see the fact  directly. Maybe the "topological" argument translates to the language I would like to use but I don't see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $g(z) = \frac{z}{|z|} f(z)$ on $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$. Your assumption is that this extends to a map on $\Bbb{CP}^1 \setminus \{0\}$. This means that $g$ has degree zero as a map to $U(1)$ (it induces multiplication-by-zero on $H_1$), as it factors through a space with $H_1 = 0$.

For $z \in S^1$, $g(z) = z \cdot f(z)$. Degree is additive under multiplication of functions to $U(1)$, and we see that $\text{deg}(f) = -1$. However, by assumption, $f$ extends across the unit disc, and so should have degree zero. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice ! ${{}}$

Answer (score 1):

This fact can be also obvious claimed such way. As you noticed, Hopf bundle is nontrivial, which can be easily proved trough comparing fundamental groups. If there was a global section, it would split a one dimensional addendum from fibre at every point, which would be proof of bundles triviality( since the fibre is one dimensional itself). Contradiction